# Assign Python variable to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, python

i am doing maintenance on a website that is using Python and CGI. The site currently runs on Python, but for some weird reason I have to assign
a Python variable to a JavaScript variable on the same Python file. I have tried many things and they have not worked, I don't know if it's even possible to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have simplified the code just to show the variable exchange from Python to JavaScript I need to do. My Python version is 3.5.2 and the site is running on IIS server. Again thank you very much for your help and time.

```
import cgi

print('')
temp = 78 #These is the Python variable I need to assign to the Javascript variable.

print('<html>')
print('<script type="text/javascript">')
print('var x = {{temp}};') #Here's how I'm trying to assign the python variable.
print('document.write(x);')
print('document.write("HELLO PYTHON VARIABLE!!");')
print('</script>')
print('</html>')
```

Comment: Is it just a number, or does the variable hold user input? (because then there's security involved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this:

```
print ('var x = %d' % temp)

print ('var x = ' + str(temp) + ';')

print ('var x = {{temp}};'.replace("{{temp}}", str(temp)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much GantTheWanderer!! It is just numbers i wanted to exchange, both ways worked perfectly!!! I had many days stuck whit these, you just saved a lot of time, again thanks for your kind response. Best regards from Guatemala.

Comment: De nada, writing programs that write programs can be tricky at first, but with practice it become second nature.  Other pitfalls include having to deal with quotes (ie `temp = "Occam's Razor"` `print ("var x = '" + temp + "'")` you could get in trouble fast keeping track of them.

Comment: Muchas gracias otra vez Grant! Wow, you are right it is really hard to keep track of the quotes, i could not get your string example to work, but i was not taking to count that i'am using version 3.5 and i think, yours is 2.7 because of the double quotes on  "Occam's Razor" it worked for mi like this 'Occam's Razor' with a single quote, thanks for the example with strings, because i just stumble upon with exactly that issue right now, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Right on hombre!  Don't worry it wont be the last time you see such things. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
print('var x = {{temp}};') #Here's how I'm trying to assign the python variable.
```

It looks like you are trying to do a template thing without actually being in a templating engine.

Try this instead:

```
print( 'var x =' + temp + ';' )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Evan Thompson! You'r absolutely right I need to do that, in meantime, these solved mi immediate problem, it worked perfectly, thank you very much!